# automatic Facebook Login like Hootsuite with Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

How can I perform an automatic Facebook Login with the Facebook JavaScript SDK like [Hootsuite](https://hootsuite.com/) do?

With my code I can just access my Facebook app with my Facebook Account, but how can I create a non-facebook login to my website, but also be logged in to Facebook over the app?

Here is my code for normal Facebook Login:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Verbunden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'AppID',
      xfbml      : true,
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An App Login (and that is what hootsuite is using) implies that you must login to Facebook first - So there is nothing else to do. If you use the Facebook Login on hootsuite, you will need to sign in to Facebook first.

Don´t worry too much about Access Tokens, the JavaScript SDK usually takes care about that unless you want to do more complicated things like generating Extended Access Tokens and whatnot.

Login is very easy with the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.2

Just make sure you call that function on user interaction (mouse click) - else it may get blocked in the browser.

---

Edit: I see that you want to auto-login with Facebook if someone logs in on your website WITHOUT Facebook login. Well, that is not possible. Access Tokens are used for API calls, not for login. If a user is not logged in on Facebook, you can´t just log him in automatically. But you CAN store Access Tokens for later usage, those are valid even when the User is not logged in. About how to use Access Tokens and which ones are available, take a look at those articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Yeah I know that, but i want to sign in with Facebook only once to connect the Fb account with my fb app. Then I will use my normal homepage login and want to be logged in in Facebook too. I know that this requires a Access Token, but I dont know how to implement this in my code above. Have you a code example for my case?

Comment: okay. But how do Hootsuite that? I log in to Hootsuite without a Facebook Login. Only once I connect with the hootsuite fb app and then whenever I log in to Hootsuite again I am automatically logged in to Facebook. How do they do that? It can just be the Access token, but I have no example how to login just with this token..

Comment: you are not logged in on facebook, hootsuite can´t just log you in. they surely store access tokens for api calls, and it may look like you are logged in, but you are surely not.

Comment: you can´t "login with a token". tokens are used for api calls. you can call /me, for example, with a stored user token, to get the name and id of the user.

Comment: okay good to know. So what should I do when I want to post to a page wall without login. Can I store an access token so that this is possible? My problem is that I find no code examples for a API call with an access token in the Java Script SDK.

Comment: sure, for that you should use an extended page token. i will add another article in my answer. you should use php for that though. posting to a page wall is a completely different topic, so i just post an important link in the comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Comment: btw, example for an api call with access token with the js sdk:
FB.api('/me', {access_token: 'xxx'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});